# How to fail a pipeline gracefully when a variable is not defined

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines

I am using a pipeline variable to define a path for a deploy script. There is the danger that someone forgets to define the variable. What would be a good way to detect this and give the appropriate error message in the yaml script file?

I could create a PowerShell script that would fail if the variable is not defined. But I would prefer to keep it all in the yaml file.

Comment: Does Yan's idea of using powershell in yaml help you solve the problem? If you have any  question ,please feel free to ask .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PowerShell script to examine the variable value can be tiny and can still live in the YAML as the inline script of the [PowerShell task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/utility/powershell?view=azure-devops):

```YAML
- powershell:  if (!$env:MyVar) Write-Error "The variable is not set"
  displayName: Check Prerequisite Variable
  failOnStderr: true
  errorActionPreference: stop
```

I might be mistaken on syntax, but it describes the idea.